# WCF 'There was no endpoint listening at URL that could accept the message'

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, soap, azure-cloud-services

I have a WCF SOAP app that I run under Azure Cloud Services.

For about 30% of all SOAP calls that I make to the app (or my users make) I get the following error:

```
There was no endpoint listening at URL that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details., Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

I am a bit confused about this error because normally I'd expect this error to orrur always or never. 
I have checked some of the users input and I don't see anything weird with it compared to other inputs.

Comment: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly Transient errors are much moreso a thing when it comes to cloud hosting.  Might need to take that into account when developing your apps

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at it

Comment: Could it be that your service can only handle a small number of simultaneous connections, and that calls are rejected during high volume?

Comment: @DavidMakogon very unlikely, we're talking about 1 request per minute approx.